# How to increment counter based on date selection

Tags: t-sql

I have a table `chequeBounce`  with columns

> Accountid ,Accountname,Chdate,chno,chamount

Now, I am creating a query which results the count of `Accountid` in a month. I need to increment the count of current `Accountid`  month with previous month value based on date select by user.

Anybody can guide?

Comment: I'm not really sure what you're asking. Do you want a query that counts `AcountID` per month and sums that with the count of a previous month chosen by the user?

Comment: Please read [this](http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Sample data, your query and expected results will help us help you. And what software are you using, e.g. SQL Server?

Comment: Sample data is best served as [DDL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_definition_language) + [DML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Data_manipulation_language). Please [edit] your question to include it, your current attempt and your desired results. For more details, [read this.](https://dba.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2976/help-me-write-this-query-in-sql)

Comment: @bhavnadubey - How's it going? Did you solve your problem?

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to know exactly what it is that you want from your question, but I made a few assumptions myself and came up with a stored procedure that might do what you want. The reason I choose a stored procedure is beacuse you imply that there should be a user defined variable. 
So first of all, create this Stored Procedure:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.Get_Count 
    @month1 int,
    @month2 int
AS
    SELECT [source].AccountName, sum([source].chamount) as [sum of amount], count([source].AccountID) as [no of AccountID in specified months] FROM
        (SELECT 
            AccountID, AccountName, chno, chamount 
        FROM chequeBounce 
        WHERE 
            MONTH(Chdate) = @month1
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 
            AccountID, AccountName, chno, chamount 
        FROM chequeBounce 
        WHERE 
            MONTH(Chdate) = @month2) as [source]
    GROUP BY [source].AccountID, [source].AccountName, [source].chamount
RETURN 0
```

This Stored Procedure takes two parameters, `@month1`, and `@month2`. Then it runs two queries. One with a where statement that matches `@month1` and another that does the exact same, but on `@month2`. It then unions them both together into one query and counts how many entries there is on each `AccountID` for the specified months. It allso sums the amount up the same way. You run the procedure by typing `exec Get_Count` followed by the two months you want to count on. Like this, if you want February and March:

```
exec Get_Count 2, 3
```

The results from above query could look something like this:

```
AccountName                                        sum of amount         no of AccountID in specified months
-------------------------------------------------- --------------------- ---------------
NameOne                                            200.00                2
NameTwo                                            100.00                1
NameThree                                          100.00                1
NameFour                                           200.00                2
NameFive                                           100.00                1
```

In this example `no of AccountID in specified months` is the count of how many occurences there is on each accountID for the specified months (2, 3).

This is the data I've used:

```
create table chequeBounce (
    AccountID int,
    AccountName varchar(50),
    Chdate date,
    chno int,
    chamount money,
)

insert into chequeBounce VALUES
    (1, 'NameOne', GETDATE(), 123, 100)
    ,(2, 'NameTwo', GETDATE(), 123, 100)
    ,(3, 'NameThree', GETDATE(), 123, 100)
    ,(4, 'NameFour', GETDATE(), 123, 100)
    ,(5, 'NameFive', GETDATE(), 123, 100)
    ,(1, 'NameOne', DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(2, 'NameTwo', DATEADD(mm, -2, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(4, 'NameFour', DATEADD(mm, -4, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(5, 'NameFive', DATEADD(mm, -5, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(1, 'NameOne', DATEADD(mm, -2, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(2, 'NameTwo', DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(4, 'NameFour', DATEADD(mm, -5, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(4, 'NameFour', DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(4, 'NameFour', DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(5, 'NameFive', DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(1, 'NameOne', DATEADD(mm, -5, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(3, 'NameThree', DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(4, 'NameFour', DATEADD(mm, -1, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
    ,(5, 'NameFive', DATEADD(mm, -3, GETDATE()), 123, 100)
```

#### Feel free to ask any questions if I did not make this very clear :)